# Why do materials & textures look different in material mode & Cycles render mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I'm at a loss :/ My textures and materials look completely different in the Cycles render view vs. the Materials or Textures view. I'm confident there is a fairly obvious piece I am missing. I'm fairly new to Blender, but have not been able to successfully find another question dealing with this exact issue.

- Roof faces were selected and then unwrapped/
- Texture is a straightforward image texture.

*What am I missing?*

## UV Wrap & Texture

[image: UV Wrap]

## Rendered View of the Roof

[image: Rendered View of the Roof]

## Material View of the Roof

[image: Material View of the Roof]

## Roof Material Preview

[image: Roof Material Preview]

Comment: you are not using texture coordinates to map the image on your material... Add a texure coordinates node plug the UV socket to the vector socket for the image texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles is not using the UV map.
add a *Texture coordinate node* and connect the *UV* output to the *Vector* input of your *image texture*.

[image]

Comment: I tried inputting texture coordinates just like this. I did it using both a box and flat projection to no avail. It does in fact connect up the UV map but that UV map has no effect on the Cycles render. The render, even with this set up, still looks wonky and curved like in the original photo :/

Comment: do you have more than one material ? you need to do this for every material if you do

Comment: Yeah, I have added *texture coordinate nodes* to all three of my materials, still the same output.

Comment: I think the issue might relate to that particular mesh. I just made a box and a sphere and they look great and functions as normal.

Comment: Did you unwrap all the faces? from the first and second screenshot, only some faces are selected, if some of them aren't unwrapped they can be the cause of the stretching, also in the UV image editor you are seeing the uv map without the image, you should have both visible to know what face is mapped to what part of the texture.

Comment: Ends up I had two issues. One was needing the *texture coordinate nodes* and the second was a previously generated *UV Map* in the Objects UV Map List incorrectly set with the littler camera icon as *Set this map as active for rendering*